# When saving a raster as .rds, the file size decreases to 1 KB. What could be causing this?

Tags: raster, r, terra

I'm changing the projection of some rasters (.tif, around 12 MB) and saving them as .rds but the result is a 1 KB file.

I'm using a for loop to create directories for each year and raster (a layer of land use type), so my script looks like this:

```
for(file in allfiles){ 
  lu = rast(file.path(inDir,file))
  yearOf = str_extract(file, regexp) 
  typelulc = str_match(file, patt)[,2]

  yearDir <- paste0(yearOf)
  if (!dir.exists(yearDir)) {
    dir.create(yearDir)
  }
  
  landuseDir <- paste0(yearDir, "/", gsub("_", "", typelulc))
  if (!dir.exists(landuseDir)) {
    dir.create(landuseDir)
  }
  
  lulonlat <- terra::project(lu, crs(ch1), method="near")
  
  terra::saveRDS(lulonlat, file = file.path(landuseDir, paste0("lu_", yearOf, '_', typelulc, '.rds')), compress = T)
```

I suspect the tiny size of the .rds has something to do with the following. When I start running the loop I get this message:

```
proj_create_from_database: datum not found
proj_create_from_database: ellipsoid not found
proj_create_from_database: prime meridian not found
proj_create_from_database: datum not found
proj_create_from_database: ellipsoid not found
proj_create_from_database: prime meridian not found
proj_create_from_database: datum not found
proj_create_from_database: ellipsoid not found
proj_create_from_database: prime meridian not found
```

However, when I use "rast" to import one of the rasters I'm trying to reproject (for example, lu.tif) you can see that there is datum and ellipsoid:

```
> lu
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 36828, 45995, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
extent      : 433390, 893340, 6039570, 6407850  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N (EPSG:25832) 
source      : lu.tif 
name        : C_01 
min value   :    0 
max value   :    1
```

Answer (score 2):

A large `terra` raster isn't stored in R's memory, but is accessed whenever `terra` functions need to get information from the file. Your raster looks big enough that it won't be stored in memory. The RDS file will not contain the data, only a reference to the file. You can test this using the `inMemory` function of `terra`.

If you delete the referenced .tif, I suspect the RDS will stop working.  RDS is not a reliable way to store rasters from `terra`, write them to GeoTIFF instead using `writeRaster`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This means that I should include writeRaster in the for loop and I guess I have to keep both, the .rds and the .tif, in the same folder? I'm confused because I used saveRDS before to save spatRasters and the result was a .rds file with a coherent size and I didn't save as .tif

Comment: a small raster, held in memory, might work when saved as an RDS file. A large raster, not stored in memory, probably won't. I recommend *not* saving as RDS, *only* save rasters as GeoTIFF files using `writeRaster`. I don't see a significant advantage to saving as RDS.

Comment: Thanks. I need to save as RDS because I'm using a pipeline that requires all rasters to be saved as RDS. Is it possible to save as TIF and then transform to RDS?

Comment: I've answered the original question about why a saved raster is so small as an RDS. If you have further problems with your pipeline, mark this Q as answered and express your new problems in a fresh question. To me the requirement for RDS sounds unachievable within a degree of convenience but make a new Q with details and I might see it.